# system.xml.xmldocument as custom activity in wf4

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I need to be able to use System.Xml.XmlDocument in my workflow diagram.

Basically, I need to load an xml file and return the content of the file as Response in a Sequential Service.

I am trying to use the InvokeMethod activity, set the targetobject to 'New XmlDocument', Method to 'Load', added a Parameter to pass the xml file path.

But how do I get the xmldocument.outerxml value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a variable for the XmlDocument and initialize it to New XmlDocument. Now use that variable as the TargetObject on the InvokeMethod instead. After the InvokeMethod use an Assign to set the XmlDocument's to your workflow's out argument.

Comment: I did declare a variable and set it as TargetObject. How do I call the Load method to pass an xml to it. I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Set the MethodName argument to "Load" and pass the the XML to it via the Parameters argument.